Distributing elements of a multi-set to triplets with certain properties possible?
Let $M$ be the multi-set which contains exactly $7$ copies of each positive integer from $1$ to $15$.
That is, $M=${$1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,\ldots , 15,15,15,15,15,15,15$}.
Is it possible to distribute the $105$ elements of $M$ to $35$ triplets $T_1, T_2, \ldots , T_{35}$ such that
$|T_i\cap T_j|\leq 1$ for every $1\leq i\neq j\leq 35$ ?
I would also be interested in generalisations and references (if there is a famous theorem behind).
Thank you.

Yes, such a partition exists! Let's first build some intuition for why these constraints are so tight.
Assuming that triples are supposed to have three distinct elements: Observe that for any distinct $a, b \in \{1, \ldots, 15\}$, there can exist at most one triple containing both $a$ and $b$. There are ${15 \choose 2} = 105$ choices for the pair $a$ and $b$. On the other hand, for each triple, we have $3$ subsets of size $2$. Thus, we have $35 \cdot 3 = 105$ pairs actually realized, that's all of them!
Now, we know that any two elements are in precisely one triple and any two triples intersect at most once. This sounds like a geometry problem! If you think about the $15$ elements as points and the triples as lines, then what we are looking for is a geometric model $X$ such that:

$X$ has $15$ points and $35$ lines
Each point is contained in $7$ lines
Each line contains $3$ points

The space you want is the projective space $\mathbb{P}^3(\mathbb{F}_2)$. Indeed, any point is contained in $7$ lines (this corresponds to the number of lines in $\mathbb{F}_2^3$, the quotient space of $\mathbb{F}_2^4$ by a line. Here, a line in $\mathbb{F}_2^4$ is a point in $\mathbb{P}^3$). Any line contains $3$ points (this corresponds to the number of lines in $\mathbb{F}_2^2$). The number of points and lines are $q$-binomial coefficients which you can verify to be $15$ and $35$.
